# What is this Lockheed Martin plane?

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle, aircraft-identification, experimental-aircraft, lockheed-martin

[image]

It's on a Lockheed Martin banner showcasing the company's iconic planes. The plane to the left on a crimson background is the U2, and the plane to the right on a blue & tan background is the C130.

It looks like a prototype UAS.

Comment: I've seen artist impression of this thing before, possibly even a model. If memory serves, it's a concept UCAV for the US Navy.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Lockheed Martin Sabre Warrior UCAV (concept):

[image]
<sup>[Source](https://defence.ru/article/7128/)</sup>

[image]
<sup>[Source](https://desuarchive.org/k/thread/32367864/)</sup>

From [Defence Forum India](http://defenceforumindia.com/forum/threads/uavs-and-ucavs.3632/page-31):

> The Sabre Warrior drone is 46 feet long, with a 36-foot wingspan,
>   capable of taking off with 30,000 pounds of load using a 22,000-pound
>   trust afterburning turbofan engine. It has two modular payload
>   sections, which can be changed by soldiers in the field. Each bay can
>   handle one 2,000 pound or two AIM-120 AMRAAM missiles or 10 smart
>   bombs or sensors, or even fuel for extended range missions—”even
>   while this thing is air refuelable.
>
> Its twin nose can also hold multiple sensors, which are
>   interchangeable. And it is designed so there could be a version with a
>   cockpit, so they can send man version as an on-the-scene controller,
>   overlooking over the unmanned versions.

- The Raptor F-22 is a 5th generation fighter, Sabre Warrior the 6th.
- Requirements worked with DARPA and USAF.
- It has been considered for the UK [Future Offensive Air System (FOAS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_Offensive_Air_System), cancelled in 2005.
- More on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qDenDFKhWN8).

Comment: Looks like something from a sci-fi movie. Very neat.

Comment: I fully expected the answer to be, "it is concept nonsense."  Good answer.  Thank you.